# Popular tabela no carregamento da página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, csv

Olá. Estou criando uma página de cadastro de pessoas, a cada clique no botão salvar é gerado um arquivo csv que no próximo carregamento da página deve ser usado para mostrar na tela os cadastros já feitos, de modo a fazer com que o usuário consiga saber quem já está cadastrado e não duplique o processo. Eu não estou conseguindo fazer com que os dados salvos no csv sejam mostrados em seus respectivos campos após a página ser carregada. Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço. O código que tenho até o momento é esse:

```
     <?php
    //$csv = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/dados.csv");
    //echo $csv;
    //$multicasts = str_getcsv ($csv);
$meuArray = Array();
$file = fopen('dados.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
  $meuArray[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
print_r($meuArray);
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Cadastro</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
      body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif }
      #tudo{ border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;width:550px;margin:0 auto }
      .bd_titulo{
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#CCCCCC;
        font-weight:bold
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".telefone").inputmask({
            mask: ["(99)99999-9999"],
            keepStatic: true
          });
        });

    $(function () {
      $(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
          novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
          novoCampo.find("input").val("");
          novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
        $(".telefone").inputmask({
            mask: ["(99)99999-9999"],
            keepStatic: true
          });
      });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post" name="cadastro" action="">
    <div id="tudo">
    <table id = "multiTable" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
      <tr><td colspan="4" class="bd_titulo">Cadastro-Pessoas</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Nome</td><td class="bd_titulo">Telefone</td><td class="bd_titulo">Função</td><td class="bd_titulo">Setor</td></tr>
      <tr class="linhas">

        <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" style="text-align:center" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="telefone[]" class = "telefone"/></td>
        <td>
          <select name="funcao[]">
          <option>Selecione</option>
          <option value="vendedor" >vendedor</option>
          <option value="gerente" >gerente</option>
          <option value="assistente" >assistente</option>          
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><select name="setor[]">
          <option>Selecione</option>
          <option value="loja" >loja</option>
          <option value="escritório" >escritório</option>        
          </select>
        </td></td>
        </tr>

      <tr><td colspan="4">
            <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="add.svg" border="0" /></a>
        </td></tr>

        <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="0">
            <td align="right" colspan="4"><input type="submit" id="Salvar" value="Salvar" /></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php 
     if ($_POST){
       $nome = $_POST['nome'];
       $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
       $funcao = $_POST['funcao'];
       $setor = $_POST['setor'];

       $quant_linhas = count($nome);
       $dados = "";

       for ($i=0; $i<$quant_linhas; $i++) {
            $dados .=  "$nome[$i],";
            $dados .= "$telefone[$i],";
            $dados .= "$funcao[$i],";
            $dados .= "$setor[$i]";
            $dados .= "\n";
          } 

      $fileName = "dados.csv"; 
      $fileHandle = fopen($fileName,"w"); 
      fwrite($fileHandle,"$dados"); 
      fclose($fileHandle);
      $file = fopen($fileName, 'r'); 
      fclose($file);

    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

amigo os nomes dos seus inputs estão diferentes das chaves que vc esta usando no php,

no input esta 'nome[]'
no na chave esta 'nome'

vc não pode fazer isso, os nomes devem ser identicos

e ainda existem outros erros

Answer (score 0):

Fiz outros ajustes pra vc, esta funcionando, como eu acredito, q vc queria.

```
<?php
```

if ($_POST){

$nome1 = $_POST['nome'];

$telpref = $_POST['tel'];

$origem1 = $_POST['funcao'];

$destino1 = $_POST['setor'];

//$quant_linhas = count($nome);

$dados .=  "$nome1,";

$dados .= "$telpref,";

$dados .= "$origem1,";

$dados .= "$destino1";

$dados .= "\n";

$fileName = "dados.csv";

$fileHandle = fopen($fileName,"a");

fwrite($fileHandle,"$dados");

fclose($fileHandle);

$file = fopen($fileName, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  echo $line[0].', '.$line[1].', '.$line[2].', '.$line[3].'

';
}
fclose($file);

}

?>

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. Então, o que tu me passou está fazendo o mesmo que eu tinha conseguido dando echo no file_get_contents do csv. Ele plota o que tá salvo no csv fora dos inputs correspondentes. Eu queria que ele plotasse dentro, tipo no nome ter três linhas salvas, uma escrito maria, outra joão e outra ze e assim por diante. Eu editei o post com uma imagem pra melhor visualização.

Answer (score 0):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não seria isso ?

tenta arrumar algo assim na tua tabela

```
    $file = fopen("dados.csv", 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements
    echo '<tr>'. 
        $line[0].', '.$line[1].', '.$line[2].', '.$line[3].'</p>'
        .'<tr>';
    }
    fclose($file);
```

Comment: Não. Eu queria que os dados ficassem salvos dentro dos inputs (no quadradinho referente a cada parâmetro). Dessa maneira eu consegui fazer, não sei é como colocar dentro do input. Eu tinha pensado em fazer um array em que eu conseguisse manter o índice da coluna e variar a linha. Assim, eu teria que sempre o valor [0] correspondente a coluna do array seria um nome. Essa parte eu consegui fazer, vou editar o arquivo novamente e colocar, eu só não sei como colocar dentro do quadradinho do input o valor.

Comment: de qual input vc quer colocar ?

Comment: Tipo, eu tenho o quadradinho do nome, se eu tivesse 3 nomes salvos no csv, por exemplo, eu queria que fossem adicionadas 3 linhas com os nomes salvos quando apágina fosse recarregada. Isso pra todos os quatro campos. Daí a tabela que eu fiz ficaria com as três linhas de dados salvos + a linha em branco pra adicionar. Conseguiu entender mais ou menos?